# Apache POI CellStyle is not getting applied

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I tried to write data, i also wrote code to set Cell Style using Cell Style class. after execution of the code. it creates excel file with just data not cell Styles. Can anyone please tell me why? I also search everywhere. My Code is same as what every where suggested.

```
CellStyle styleGreen = cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
styleGreen.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM_DASHED);
cell.setCellStyle(sty‌​leGreen);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post your code ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Could you please update your question with all the nécessary code (including file creation, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

Re-using your code I simply wrote :

```
CellStyle styleGreen = cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

styleGreen.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM_DASHED);

cell.setCellValue("value"); // testing with some value in the cell
cell.setCellStyle(styleGreen);
```

And it worked , that's why I suppose the error come from your following code , **make sure you do not re-use this style in your code below** otherwise you'll end up modifying the previous cells, instead just create a new one.