# POI CellStyle does not appear to be applied

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, styling

**Please note:** I see a *very* similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276000/apache-poi-cellstyle-is-not-getting-applied) but that answer was not very conclusive (I can't discern what the actual fix is/was). If someone can explain to me how that question/answer addresses my present issue at hand, I will happily delete this question myself! Just please don't DV/CV as a "dupe", and instead please help me make sense of that provided solution!

---

Java 8 and POI 4.1.x here. I am trying to write some Java/POI code that will produce a styled/formatted Excel file as output. I have created [this GitHub project](https://github.com/bitbythecron/hello-windows) that perfectly reproduces the issue I'm seeing. If you *really want*, you can take a look at it and run it (its a Swing app) via `./gradlew clean build shadowJar && java -jar build/libs/hello-windows.jar`, but the TLDR; of it is:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SOME_SHEET");

Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
headerFont.setBold(true);

CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

int rowNum = 0;

Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
headerRow.setRowStyle(cellStyle);

Cell partNumberHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(0);
partNumberHeaderCell.setCellValue("Part #");
partNumberHeaderCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

Cell partDescriptionHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(1);
partDescriptionHeaderCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
partDescriptionHeaderCell.setCellValue("Description");

Cell partPriceHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(2);
partPriceHeaderCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
partPriceHeaderCell.setCellValue("Price");

Cell manufacturerHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(3);
manufacturerHeaderCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
manufacturerHeaderCell.setCellValue("Make");

rowNum++;

Row nextRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

nextRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(uuid);
nextRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Some Part");
nextRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(2.99);
nextRow.createCell(3).setCellValue("ACME");

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("acme.xlsx");

    workbook.write(fos);

    workbook.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
}
```

When this code runs it produces an Excel file that contains all my data (the header row and a "data" row) correctly, **however** all the formatting and cell styling seems to be ignored:

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see that the header is not styled at all, however I *believe* I am styling it correctly:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

If my code is correct then I should see a header that:

1. Has a yellow background; and
2. Is horizontally-centered/aligned; and
3. Is bolded

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear why the bold font not gets applied for you, for me it gets.

But the problem with the cell interior is that `Excel` cell interiors have pattern fills. There the fill background color is the color behind the pattern and the fill foreground color is the color of the pattern. Solid filled cell interiors must have solid pattern having the needed fill foreground color set.

See also [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills).

```
...
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
//cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
...
```

Let's have a complete example which will store your data in an `Excel` sheet:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelCellStyle {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
   headerFont.setBold(true);

   CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
   headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
   headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   headerStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

   Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
    new Object[] {"Part #", "Description", "Price", "Make"},
    new Object[] {"cb82c02", "Some Part", 2.99, "ACME"}
   };

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (r==0) cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
     Object content = data[r][c];
     if (content instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)content);
     } else if (content instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)content);
     }
    }
   }

   for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey it works, thanks @Axel Richter (+1)!!! I can confirm that the font bolding is _actually_ working. I am on a Mac and use the **Numbers** app to open/edit XLSX files, and for some reason Numbers doesn't like the bolding. But when I open the output file in Excel (on a difference machine) the bolding shows up! Two quick followup questions for you, if you don't mind?

Comment: **(1)** why does setting `setFillForegroundColor` work, instead of `setFillBackgroundColor`? To me, the "foreground" would be the text, and the "background" is the whitespace behind the text. Does Excel/POI have a different concept of foreground vs background?

Comment: And **(2)** is there any way to set the column widths so that they never overlap the header text values? See my screenshot up above where the `Description` header is truncated as `Descriptio` (missing the "n"). In order to see the "n" you have to manually resize the column. I'd love to be able to just open up Excel and see the whole header name without having to resize any columns. Is this possible?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253199/how-to-set-bold-font-using-the-latest-apache-poi/49270169#49270169 for your `Numbers` problem on `Mac`. To your follow up questions: (1): Please read my answer. This is explained in second paragraph. (2): Please try my code. This is done by `Sheet.autoSizeColumn`.

Comment: Thanks again @Axel!